# How do I control the visibility of a Button according to a field on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, button, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a Reward page in my Application. The item's button will be available if the user have the `Less or Equal to` the number of field `BloodDonated` in my Firebase. The item itself hold the requirement needed by the user to claim the reward.

Below, I am not able to claim the last reward since it requires `20` and the user only have `12`, in this context, the amount of blood donated. How do I make the `Button` for the last reward invisible for the user?

**Relevant Picture:**

[image]

**my Firebase:**

[image]

**My Adapter**

```
public class RewardAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<RewardModel, RewardAdapter.RewardViewHolder> {

public RewardAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<RewardModel> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RewardAdapter.RewardViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull RewardModel model) {
    holder.rank.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
    Double dq = model.getDonationReq();
    holder.donationRequired.setText(String.format("%.0f", dq));
    holder.rewardDescription.setText(model.getRewardDesc());

    holder.claim_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //
        }
    });
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RewardAdapter.RewardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(com.example.loginregisterfire.R.layout.list_rewards_single, parent, false);
    return new RewardViewHolder(view);
}

public class RewardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView rank;
    TextView donationRequired;
    TextView rewardDescription;
    Button claim_btn;

    public RewardViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        rank = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rewards_rank);
        donationRequired = itemView.findViewById(R.id.single_reward_amount);
        rewardDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.single_reward_desc);
        claim_btn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.claim_btn);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle the Button visibility within `onBindViewHolder()` by comparing the user value to 20

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RewardAdapter.RewardViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull RewardModel model) {
    holder.rank.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
    Double dq = model.getDonationReq();
    holder.donationRequired.setText(String.format("%.0f", dq));
    holder.rewardDescription.setText(model.getRewardDesc());
    
    holder.claim_btn.setVisibility(dq >= 20 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE); // <<< Here is the change
    
    holder.claim_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // 
        }
    });
}
```